# Waypoint unrecognized on Ajax-loaded content

Tags: ajax, jquery, jquery-waypoints

I'm loading a page into a div. I'm also attempting to establish a waypoint, so that when the user scrolls down the page, the menu will change colors.

The problem I am having is the new height of the div is not recognized by the browser once the ajax content is loaded.

Here's what I have:

```
$(".cta").live('click', function () {
    $('#faq').load('about-us/faqs/index.html'),
    function () {
        $("#faq").waypoint(function (event, direction) {
            if (direction === 'up') {
                $("#siteNav li a").removeClass("siteNavSelected");
                $("#siteNav li.nav3 a").addClass("siteNavSelected");
            }
        }, {
            offset: function () {
                return $.waypoints('viewportHeight') - $("#faq").outerHeight();
            }

        });
    }
    return false;
});
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use `$.waypoints('refresh');`, from the documentation:

> This will force a recalculation of each waypoint’s trigger point based on its offset option. This is called automatically whenever the window is resized or new waypoints are added. **If your project is changing the DOM or page layout without doing one of these things, you may want to manually call it.**

Comment: I found that adding `$.waypoints('refresh');` solved my issue of the waypoint events not triggering after AJAX content was injected into the page. Thanks Svilen.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the intrinsics of the `waypoint` plugin, but you could also bind a scroll event and then capture the `.scrollTop()` value. Would look something like this:

```
$(document).bind('scroll', function(event) {        
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scrollTop < 1000 && $('siteNav li').hasClass('styleA')) { return; }
    else { 
        $('siteNav li').removeClass('styleB');
        $('siteNav li').addClass('styleA');
    }
    if (scrollTop > 1000 && $('siteNav li').hasClass('styleB')) { return; }
    else {
        $('siteNav li').removeClass('styleA');
        $('siteNav li').addClass('styleB');
    }
});
```

You have to play with the values a little to get it acting at the right spot. Also you have to use a greater or less than value in the test as if a user is at the top of the page and uses the scroll-wheel on his mouse to fly down the page, you don't get every value in between.